# How to store adresses in an array - C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

```
My Code example:

char* array = new char[10];
char* str;
int j = 0;

MyClass(char* input){                  //input = sentence columns terminated by '\n'

   str = new char[strlen(input)];

   for(int i=0; i<strlen(input); i++){
      if (input[i] == '\n'){           //look for end of line
         str[i] = '\0';                //add \0 Terminator for char[]
         array[j] = &(str[i]);         //store address of sentence beginning in array
         j++;
      }
      else{
         str[i] = input[i];
      }
   }
}
```

How do i store an address into an array. So i can get the beginning address of a sentence by number. I created a solution with a vector storing my sentences as char* objects. But there must be a way without vectors?!

EDIT:

This is my solution.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Pointer{

public:

    char** array = new char*[10];
    char* str;
    char* buffer;
    int j = 1;

    Pointer(char* input){
        str = new char[strlen(input)];
        array[0] = str;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
            if (input[i] == '\n'){
                str[i] = '\0';
                array[j] = &(str[i]) + sizeof(char);
                j++;
            }
            else{
                str[i] = input[i];
            }
        }
    }

    void output(int i){
        buffer = array[i];
        cout<<buffer;
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You have a possible overflow error, as `strlen` gives you the length of the string *without* the terminator.

Comment: As for your problem, `array` is not an array of pointers, it's an array of *characters*.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using vectors?

Comment: You can store `char` pointers in an array like this: `char* array[size]` or dynamically `char** array`

Comment: And finally, is there a reason you don't use e.g. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and other tools available in the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)?

Comment: so: char** array = new char*[10]; ?

Comment: @stunner2002 Yes. That's an array of 10 `char` pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use std containers for that (`std::vector<std::string>`). Anyway, if you do need to have it the C way:

In this line:

```
array[j] = &(str[i]);
```

you are storing an address of *ith* character of the string. If you want to store the pointer to entire string, use:

```
array[j] = str;
```

Please note you have numerous other errors in your code.
For example, you should not be using a constant size array for that, as you're risking undefined behaviour in case you have more lines in your text.

Btw. `MyClass` is a function, not a class.

Comment: `char* array = new char*[10]` That will not compile.

Comment: char** array = new char*[10] will compile. MyClass(char* input) is my constructor.

Comment: My bad! Sorry for that, removing.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to actual question:

```
char ** array = new (char *)[10];
```

What you should probably do instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> array;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* array[10]
char* str;
int j = 0;

MyClass(char* input){                  //input = sentence columns terminated by '\n'

    str = new char[strlen(input)];

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(input); i++){
        if (input[i] == '\n'){          //look for end of line
            str[i] = '\0';              //add \0 Terminator for char[]
            array[j] = str;         //store address of sentence beginning in array
            // or you can use
            // array[j] = &(str[0]);
            j++;
        }
        else{
            str[i] = input[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not fix the no space for the terminator bug. Although I guess the assumption is there will always be at least 1 '\n' in the input. I would still address the bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pointer{

public:    
    Pointer(std::string input){
            addresses = split(input, '\n', addresses);
    }

    void output(int i){
            std::cout << addresses.at(i);
    }

private:

    std::vector<std::string> addresses;
};
```